# SQL Update Query error dont know whats going wrong

Tags: php, mysql

SQL query:

```
UPDATE a2418693_GCM.driver SET lat = 78.54555,
LONG = 78.45544252 WHERE username =  'rakesh'
```

MySQL Message: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'long=78.45544252 WHERE username='rakesh'' at line 2

Whats the problem here?

I am using the following query..

```
update a2418693_GCM.driver 
SET lat=78.54555,long=78.45544252 WHERE username='rakesh'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's giving you a `syntax error` because you are using a reserved MySQL keyword "long". To fix this, you need to either rename your column or escape it the "MySQL" way using backticks

```
UPDATE `a2418693_GCM`.`driver` SET 
`lat` ='78.54555',
`long` ='78.45544252' 
WHERE `username` ='rakesh'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a2418693_GCM.driver SET lat = 78.54555,
longitude = 78.45544252 WHERE username =  'rakesh'
```

since long is a data type
so I used longitude in place of long

Comment: You can escape the name with the answer below, no need to rename. You can see a list of reserved terms here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html.